# NamedPipeServerStream/NamedPipeClientStream wrapper

Tags: c#, multithreading, named-pipes

I'm currently writing a small wrapper for `NamedPipeServerStream`/`NamedPipeClientStream` that is fully `Event` based as oppose to using `AsyncCallbacks`.

I expose sync and async methods for pretty much everything possible (connecting/waiting for connection, writing, etc) so if a consumer wanted to, for example, start a server instance and send a message when a client connects he could either go full sync route and do something like ...

```
var server = new NamedPipeServer("helloWorld");
server.StartAndWait();
server.Write("Welcome!");
```

or the async way like...

```
var server = new NamedPipeServer("helloWorld);
server.ClientConnected += x => x.WriteAsync("Welcome!");
server.Start(); //Start() returns immediately
```

However I'm struggling with finding a good way to do the same for reading messages. Currently when a message is read I fire a `MessageAvailable` event and pass the message in as one of the arguments.

I just can't come up with a proper way of implementing synchronous reads.

What I've considered is the following:

Having a `GetNextMessage()` sync method that gets the message. Internally, this could be handled in two different ways:

- I could keep an `IEnumerable<Message>` with all of the not yet consumed messages. So as soon as the other side sends a message, I'd read it from the stream and store it in memory so they can be later consumed by `GetNextMessage()`. The advantage is that it frees up the stream pretty much as soon as the message is written, so it doesn't block the other side from sending other messages. The disadvantage is that I have absolutely no control over how many messages I'll be holding or the size of them. My `IEnumerable<Message>` might end up having 10GB worth of non-consumed messages, and there's nothing I can do about it since I can't force the consumer to retrieve messages.
- I could take the view that I only ever store one message in an internal buffer, and only ever start reading again once that one was consumed via `GetNextMessage()`. If I do that though, the other side would be prevented from writing other messages until the previous one was consumed. To be more exact, the other side would be able to write until the stream is full. Which could be either multiple small complete messages or a single incomplete message. In the case of an incomplete single message I think this is a worse approach because in between part 1 of the message being sent and subsequent parts, the other end might end up disconnecting and the whole message will be lost.

To make things harder, in either of the approaches above there's always the chance that the consumer is using events for receiving messages (remember the event contains the message received) and therefore has no need for `GetNextMessage()`. I'd either need to stop sending the message in the event altogether, or find a way of not pushing the event to the internal buffer if the message is consumed via the event. And while I can easily tell whether there is an event handler or not, there's no way of knowing if the message is actually being handled there (i.e., consider a class implementing this one and listens to that event, yet does nothing with it). The only real approach I can see here is to remove the message from the event, force consumers to always call `GetNextMessage()`, but am open to other ideas.

There's also another problem with either of the approaches, which is the fact that I can't control the order in which the messages are sent if `WriteAsync()` is used (or `Write()` is used from different threads).

Can anyone think of a better way of tackling this problem?

Comment: And what happens with messages received before someone subscribed to your `MessageAvailable`? Are they just lost?

Comment: Currently, where there is no `GetNextMessage()`, yes. If there was a `GetNextMessage()` then no. But also this is the reason why both the client and the server has a `Start()` method. So you can subscribe to events *before* you even try to connect. The same could be said for all other events though `Connected`, `Disconnected` etc ... The idea is if you care about it you subscribe before calling `Start()`

Comment: Maybe instead of GetNextMessage use GetMessageStream which will return IEnumerable. Iterating over that enumerable will block until new message is available.

Comment: That still leaves me in a situation where I could end up storing 10GB of messages locally since I have no control over when the client consumes them.

Comment: Yes but that is inevitable and it's clients problem. Or you mean you worry that you should store them always, even if client did not call GetMessageStream?

Comment: Assuming GetMessageStream, whenever GetMessageStream is called, all stored messages should be released. Any messages received after that should be stored until the next GetMessageStream is called. However I have no control over when the next GetMessageStream is called (if ever).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159689/discussion-between-cogumel0-and-evk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach. Create interface:

```
public interface ISubscription : IDisposable {
    Message NextMessage(TimeSpan? timeout);
}

public class Message {

}
```

And then implement like that:

```
public class NamedPipeServer {        
    public void StartAndWait() {

    }

    public ISubscription StartAndSubscribe() {
        // prevent race condition before Start and subscribing to MessageAvailable
        var subscription = new Subscription(this);
        StartAndWait();
        return subscription;
    }

    public ISubscription Subscribe() {
        // if user wants to subscribe and some point after start - why not
        return new Subscription(this);
    }

    public event Action<Message> MessageAvailable;

    private class Subscription : ISubscription {
        // buffer
        private readonly BlockingCollection<Message> _queue = new BlockingCollection<Message>(
            new ConcurrentQueue<Message>());

        private readonly NamedPipeServer _server;

        public Subscription(NamedPipeServer server) {
            // subscribe to event
            _server = server;
            _server.MessageAvailable += OnMessageAvailable;
        }

        public Message NextMessage(TimeSpan? timeout) {
            // this is blocking call
            if (timeout == null)
                return _queue.Take();
            else {
                Message tmp;
                if (_queue.TryTake(out tmp, timeout.Value))
                    return tmp;
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void OnMessageAvailable(Message msg) {
            // add to buffer
            _queue.Add(msg);
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            // clean up
            _server.MessageAvailable -= OnMessageAvailable;
            _queue.CompleteAdding();
            _queue.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Client then either calls `Subscribe` or `StartAndSubscribe`.

```
var sub = server.StartAndSubscribe();
var message = sub.NextMessage();
var messageOrNull = sub.NextMessage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
sub.Dispose();
```

That way if no one subscribes - you buffer no messages. And if someone subscribes and then does not consume - it's their problem, not yours, because buffering happens in subscription they now own. You can also limit size of `_queue` blocking collection, then adding to it will block if limit is reached, blocking your `MessageAvailable` event, but I won't recommend doing that.

Comment: Umm... It seems that the only difference is you're adding a subscription mechanism and you only buffer when someone subscribes. I sort of agree with that, but... A) It seems to detract somewhat from how NamedPipes work by default. I see NamedPipes as being low level enough to not have that at all and I'd like to keep my wrapper as low level as well. B) For me subscription in implied when you create a NamedPipe with two way communication.

Comment: But you wanted `GetNextMessage` blocking call already, so why it detracts from how named pipes work? As you said it's the same call but buffering is performed only if necessary.

Comment: It just seems like you're adding another layer (the subscription) when to me subscription is implied when you create a two way communication NamedPipe. It could be argued that it's not implied for the client, that it doesn't know whether the Pipe "session" it's joining is two way or one way until after it joins, but I don't know if I'm that worried about that to be honest :P

Comment: If that's about name - you can name it differently. So when you start your session (or at any point later) - you optionally return some object which can be used to consume incoming messages in "sync" fashion. And another layer is needed to solve problems mentioned in your question.

Comment: Nothing to do with the name, but I can't see exactly which specific issues it solves. Maybe I'm missing something, but for me all this does is instead of implicitly saying that I start adding received messages to an internal queue as soon as you call `Connect()` (which is what I proposed in my question) and I have no control of when (or if) you ever consume them, I explicitly say that I only start adding messages to an internal queue when you subscribe to it (before or after calling `Connect()`), but I still have no control of when (or if) you ever consume them. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, explicit vs implicit is the main difference. If user explicitly express the intent to receive messages in sync fashion - you buffer them. Otherwise - no messages are buffered (also, buffer size may be limited, but not to 1 as you propose but for example to 100, and when buffer is full - you will buffer the rest in socket). Anyway, that's one option. I would be interested if you will find a better one which still has blocking `GetNextMessage` call.

Comment: By the way, similar concept is used in many messaging libraries, for example in rabbitmq .NET client. You either create subscription and call Next() or subscribe to event.

Comment: Another thought came to my mind. You can create two NamedPipeServer classes (with same base class of course). Not sure how to name them, but one will buffer messages and expose `NextMessage` interface (no MessageAvailable event) and second will expose just `MessageAvailable` event.

Comment: Sorry, just realized I was being dumb. See after posting... I changed my code so that it wouldn't pass the message when the event fired. It would only pass the object that fired it and *force* you to call GetNextMessage() - which meant I'd *always* keep a buffer. Whereas here you're still sending the message as part of the event and creating a subscription buffer outside of it. That allows the consumer to choose whether to use the events or a subscription. So yeah, your solution does very much make sense!

Comment: @cogumel0 good, because I was having doubts if it makes sense myself after your comments :)